# How to prove this identity: $4\cdot(\frac12)!=\pi$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial, gamma-function, irrational-numbers, pi

**Progress:** I recently found this identity on an YouTube Video: $$4\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)!=\pi$$

But it didn't provide any kind of rigorous proof or simply a 'proof' in that regard. It only showed some Calculus identities to give some insight. Also importantly this is the only identity or equation I know that exactly equals to '$\pi$'. The part which is very interesting is $(\frac{1}{2})!$, the factorial of a **fraction** not an **integer**.

So if anyone can give a rigorous proof and even elementary proof or share more heuristics and insights, it would be useful. I'll really appreciate your efforts, thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: Are you sure the question is correct? $4\cdot \left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)!=2\sqrt{\pi}$.

Maybe your question: $4\cdot  \left(\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)!\right)^2={\pi}$

Comment: I'm sure my one is the correct form. Ongky Denny Wijaya

Comment: Please see my answer. I have proved $4\cdot\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)!=2\sqrt{\pi}$, not $\pi$.

Answer (score 5):

Note that gamma function is defined as$$\Gamma{(n)}=\int x^{n-1}e^{-x}dx$$
for $n>0$, $n\in\mathbb{R}$.

Gamma function is generalization of factorial function.

$$\Gamma (n)=(n-1)!.$$

Gamma function has property
$$\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi}$$
and
$$\Gamma(n+1)=n\Gamma(n).$$

So,

\begin{align}
4\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)!&=4\left(\dfrac{3}{2}-1\right)!\\
&=4\Gamma\left(\dfrac{3}{2}\right)\\
&=4\Gamma\left(1+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\\
&=4\cdot \dfrac{1}{2} \Gamma\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\\
&=2\sqrt{\pi}.
\end{align}

> I guess you want to prove
> $$4\left(\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)!\right)^2=\pi.$$
>
> \begin{align}
>  4\left(\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)!\right)^2&=4\left(\left(\dfrac{3}{2}-1\right)!\right)^2\\
>  &=4\left(\Gamma\left(\dfrac{3}{2}\right)\right)^2\\
>  &=4\left(\Gamma\left(1+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\right)^2\\ &=4\cdot
>  \left(\dfrac{1}{2} \Gamma\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\right)^2\\ &=4\cdot
>  \left(\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi}\right)^2\\ &=4\cdot \dfrac{1}{4}\pi\\
>  &=\pi. \end{align}

Comment: Yes that's what I was looking for, thanks for the proof. Appreciated. I need to look up into some properties of Gamma function, since it involves Gamma function. @Ongky Denny Wijaya.

Answer (score 0):

Not a answer, but important to know:
As Qiaochu Yuan mentioned, the Gamma function gives your equality. But in the usual definition of the factorial it's undefined. That means the Gamma function is only one way to extend the factorial, even if it seems to be the most natural and useful way.

Comment: Actually, there are other extensions of the factorial function too: some I recall are Hadamard's gamma function and Luschny's factorial. It's just that Euler's gamma function is the most useful since it is the only analytic extension that is log-convex (cf. Bohr-Mollerup theorem) and holomorphic on the strip where $\Re z\gt 0$ and bounded on the strip where $1\leq\Re z\leq 2$ (cf. Wielandt theorem)